# Finding the best possible bound for an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Suppose $f$ is analytic in $|z|<2$ and $|f(z)|\le 2$ there, and $f(1)=0$. Find the best possible bound for $f(1/4)$.

I guess 'the best possible bound' means that the bound is as close as possible to the supremum of all possible values of $f(1/4)$. However, I can't figure out the best possible bound by the given data. It is clear that the bound is at most 2, but how can I find the smaller bound for this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D$ be the unit disk. The Schwartz lemma tells you that any holomorphic $f : D \to D$ such that $f(0) = 0$ obeys $|f(z)| \leq |z|$ for all $z \in D$. This inequality is saturated by the function $f(z) = z$.

You can easily scale this result up to a disk of radius 2.

A difficulty that you face is that your $f$ sends $1 \mapsto 0$ rather than $0 \mapsto 0$. To deal with this, you could compose your $f$ with a conformal map sending the disk to itself in such a way that $0 \mapsto 1$.

Note that a standard conformal mapping from $D \to D$ sending $\alpha \mapsto 0$ is
$$ z \mapsto \frac {z - \alpha} { 1- \bar \alpha z},$$
though again you need to scale this up to disks of radius 2.

I hope this is enough of a hint.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't think that it is related to the conformal mapping.